# Cant use php fopen() function in wordpress functions.php

Tags: php, wordpress, csv, fopen

I am trying to simple run fopen() in the **functions.php**, and have also tried it in a **test.php** wordpress template file.

But it does not work. If I move the test.php file and csv file to a location outside the theme folder then it works first time.

```
function csv_to_array($filename='', $delimiter=',')
{
    if(!file_exists($filename) || !is_readable($filename))
        return FALSE;

    $header = NULL;
    $data = array();
    if (($handle = fopen($filename, 'r')) !== FALSE)
    {
        while (($row = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, $delimiter)) !== FALSE)
        {
            if(!$header)
                $header = $row;
            else
                $data[] = array_combine($header, $row);
        }
        fclose($handle);
    }
    return $data;
}

echo '<pre>';
var_dump(csv_to_array('csv/nationality-codes.csv'));
echo '</pre>';
```

This is my folder structure in the theme file...

[image]

Any ideas why it does not work?

Comment: `fopen` will trigger a warning when it can't open a file. Enable error reporting and/or check your error log.

Comment: It opens the file fine. Just not when in the theme folder. No errors

Comment: Give some error messages in between and check where it fails.

Comment: @Joshc enable debugging and it will show you path issue

Comment: rename print_r to var_dump and check what your function returns. You can also try setting error reporting on, before function call.

Comment: debug is on, no errors. Var dump returns boo false - exactly same code in both files. Non theme file: http://www.samlowes.com/test/ . Theme template file: http://www.samlowes.com/core/test/

Comment: In addition of comments above, as loading a file, and working with the data contained in it, looks a lot like functionality and not aesthetics/theming, you should consider creating a custom functionality plugin.

Comment: OK granted. But why does it not work? It's driving me nuts. It should just open the csv just like it does outside of the theme folder

Comment: Replace your file path with the full version.  `var_dump( csv_to_array( get_template_directory() . '/csv/nationality-codes.csv' ) );`

Comment: @NathanDawson http://www.samlowes.com/core/wp-content/themes/samlowes/csv/nationality-codes

Comment: @Joshc Please test my comment above. It needs to be the file path not URL by the way. get_template_directory will return the path you need.

Comment: @nathanDawson YES dude you are legend!!! Thank you so much for helping out. You might want to make an answer out of it. Thanks

Comment: Pleased I could help. I'll turn it into an answer now :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the full file path instead of a relative one.

Use the WordPress function `get_template_directory()` to get the path to your template directory. From there add the path to your file.

Change:

```
var_dump(csv_to_array('csv/nationality-codes.csv'));
```

To:

```
var_dump( csv_to_array( get_template_directory() . 'csv/nationality-codes.csv' ) );
```

Answer (score 1):

Finally got my code working with the help from NathanDawnson.

Some reason functions.php did not like relative path. This was the fix...

```
get_template_directory() . '/csv/nationality-codes.csv'
```

See full code working.

```
// csv to array
function csv_to_array($filename='', $delimiter=',')
{
    if(!file_exists($filename) || !is_readable($filename))
        return FALSE;

    $header = NULL;
    $data = array();
    if (($handle = fopen($filename, 'r')) !== FALSE)
    {
        while (($row = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, $delimiter)) !== FALSE)
        {
            if(!$header)
                $header = $row;
            else
                $data[] = array_combine($header, $row);
        }
        fclose($handle);
    }
    return $data;
}


// rider nationality
function motocom_rider_nationality( $field )
{

    // reset choices
    $field['choices'] = array();

    // get the textarea value from options page without any formatting
    $choices = csv_to_array( get_template_directory() . '/csv/nationality-codes.csv' );

    $field['choices'] = array(
        null => 'Select nationality...'
    ); 

    // loop through array and add to field 'choices'
    if( is_array($choices) )
    {

        foreach( $choices as $choice )
        {

            $label = $choice['Country'];
            $value = $choice['A3'];

            $field['choices'][ $value ] = $label . ' [' . $value . ']';

        }
    }

    // Important: return the field
    return $field;

}
add_filter('acf/load_field/name=rider_nationality', 'motocom_rider_nationality');
```