# How to explode csv string (not csv file) safely into a usable php array

Tags: php, arrays, string, csv, explode

I am using wordpress and need to dynamically populate a dropdpown. How ever I am having issues with fopen php function in wordpress. [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21990467/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21990467/cant-use-php-fopen-function-in-wordpress-functions-php)

So I've given up trying to import csv file and resorted to just placing my csv file contents into an wordpress options field for a quick fix.

But I am struggling with exploding the csv string safely to then use specific columns for choice label and values.

Can any please advise on how I can do this?

Thank you in advance.

---

**The function**

```
// rider nationality
function motocom_rider_nationality( $field )
{

    // reset choices
    $field['choices'] = array();

    // get the textarea value from options page without any formatting
    $choices = get_field('nationality_codes', 'option', false);

    // explode the value so that each line is a new array piece
    $choices = explode(",", $choices);

    // remove any unwanted white space
    $choices = array_map('trim', $choices);

    $field['choices'] = array(
        null => 'Select nationality...'
    ); 

    // loop through array and add to field 'choices'
    if( is_array($choices) )
    {

        foreach( $choices as $choice )
        {

            $label = $choice['Country'];
            $value = $choice['A4'];

            $field['choices'][ $value ] = $label;
        }
    }

    // Important: return the field
    return $field;

}
add_filter('acf/load_field/name=rider_nationality', 'motocom_rider_nationality');
```

---

**The csv string in the options textarea field...**

```
Country,A2,A3,Number
Aaland Islands,AX,ALA,248
Afghanistan,AF,AFG,4
Albania,AL,ALB,8
Algeria,DZ,DZA,12
Samoa,AS,ASM,16
Andorra,AD,AND,20
```

---

Comment: why not use `str_getcsv()`?

Comment: [str_getcsv()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php)

Comment: Please see my comments above in question - Can't get str_getcsv to split the string in a proper array.

Comment: @Joshc: You are not splitting your input into lines, and neither does `str_getcsv` (it should be obvious from the output that the newline chars gets included into the output). `str_getcsv` works just fine, fix your code. It's also obvious that `str_getcsv` should be called inside a loop, which does not happen.

Comment: @Jon, i know code is wrong and that's why i'm trying to find a method that works.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it using this solution...

```
// csv to array
function motocom_csv_to_array($filename='', $delimiter=',')
{
    if(!file_exists($filename) || !is_readable($filename))
        return FALSE;

    $header = NULL;
    $data = array();
    if (($handle = fopen($filename, 'r')) !== FALSE)
    {
        while (($row = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, $delimiter)) !== FALSE)
        {
            if(!$header)
                $header = $row;
            else
                $data[] = array_combine($header, $row);
        }
        fclose($handle);
    }
    return $data;
}


// rider nationality
function motocom_rider_nationality( $field )
{

    // reset choices
    $field['choices'] = array();

    // get the textarea value from options page without any formatting
    $choices = motocom_csv_to_array( get_template_directory() . '/csv/nationality-codes.csv' );

    $field['choices'] = array(
        null => 'Select nationality...'
    ); 

    // loop through array and add to field 'choices'
    if( is_array($choices) )
    {

        foreach( $choices as $choice )
        {

            $label = $choice['Country'];
            $value = $choice['A3'];

            $field['choices'][ $value ] = $label . ' [' . $value . ']';

        }
    }

    // Important: return the field
    return $field;

}
add_filter('acf/load_field/name=rider_nationality', 'motocom_rider_nationality');
```