# open csv in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, csv

i have a csv file that contains some user specific data which i like to load into my template on the fly when a user access's their user area from the front end.

the csv it self gets managed outside of wordpress and gets uploaded via ftp to a specific directory in the wordpress framework.

as the csv itself contains all the data required, i didn't want to create additional processes where csv uploading to the database is necessary.

i would like to call a function within my template to read the csv file and convert it to an array so i can just manipulate the data as i wish.

i have attempted the following by inserting the following code into my template:

```
$file = fopen(get_option('siteurl') . '/wp-content/csv/userdata.csv',"r");

while(! feof($file)){
  print_r(fgetcsv($file));
}

fclose($file);
```

However this doesn't seem to work and after searching online i cant seem to figure out why. Does WordPress support what i am trying to do? if not, then what can i do to achieve this functionality. i hope i don't have to do this outside of the WordPress framework and include it to my template via an iframe.

Answer (score 1):

As you are using get_option('siteurl') which is `http://yoursiteurl`  your system will send a http request to open that file for this to work you will be need php curl extension installed in you system. Also its suggested to access file directly which is by using some thing like

```
$file = fopen(WP_CONTENT_DIR . '/csv/userdata.csv',"r");

while(! feof($file)){
  print_r(fgetcsv($file));
}

fclose($file);
```

Comment: this seems to take a very long time to load my csv and my csv isn't even big at the moment and after the load is complete it doesn't show any results

Comment: i attempted to use the function as described in this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21990467/cant-use-php-fopen-function-in-wordpress-functions-php
however i get this results: bool(false)

Answer (score 0):

my apologies...dummy me, for some reason my csv got saved as a .txt file.
this line of code worked for me:

```
array_map('str_getcsv', file(get_option('siteurl') . '/wp-content/csv/'.'userdata.txt'));
```